# Using method as a dictionary value

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = {
            'cash': 500,
            'paycheck': 1,
            'savings': 1000,
            'current_car': 0,
            'possible_cars': ['Chevy', 'Honda', 'BMW'],
            'car_cost': [0, 100, 200],
            'current_house': 0,
            'possible_houses': ['apartment','townhouse','suite'],
            'house_cost': [0, 150, 300],
            'status': self.status()
                  }

    def status(self):
        while self.inventory['cash'] + self.inventory['savings'] > 0:
            return True
```

I'm currently working through "Learn Python the Hard Way", on Exercise 45. I've created a class to list the items relevant to my game, I've stored these keys and values in a dictionary under my **init** method. Where I'm having trouble is within my last key and it's value - the 'status' key.

What I want for this value to do is reference my status method, which I've set to return true as long as my player has a positive sum of money (other portions of my game will reference .inventory['status'] to check its truth before they execute. Now I've done quick two line proof-of-concept codes to verify that it's possible to use a function as a value - where I'm getting hung up on is how to implement this within a class, specifically when my dictionary is within **init**.

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex45file1.py", line 151, in <module>
    my_inv  = Inventory() #TEST
  File "ex45file1.py", line 80, in __init__
    'status': status()
NameError: global name 'status' is not defined
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure Python is using the most recent version of your module? Try resaving and rerunning.

Comment: just made sure it was saved and ran it twice. same results

Comment: Check that the file Python is using looks the same as the code you posted. Particularly, make sure it really says `self.status()` instead of just `status()`.

Comment: sorry, looks like i did switch the code/errors. http://pastebin.com/zhvQ6wC3

Comment: This is not related to the error, but your `while` loop in the `status` method seems to be doing the work of an `if` statement. It only runs its suite at most once, since the only statement in the suite is a `return`. (This is perhaps a good thing, since if you didn't return, the loop would repeat forever, since you're also not modifying the variables it checks in its condition). You may also want to return something other than the default of `None` if the condition fails. You could use `return self.invetory['cash'] + self.inventory['savings'] > 0`, which will always return `True` or `False`

Comment: @Blckknight I had coded in this way because the class that inherits Inventory uses a while loop, which would be terminated if at any point my status() method is False. If I re-coded in the way you describe, would my other while loop still be notified if status is ever determined to be false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, that isn't the error that your code produces. In your version you have `'status': status()` but on SO you wrote `'status': self.status()`. In any case, if you fix that you still have a problem,

```
AttributeError: 'Inventory' object has no attribute 'inventory'
```

The reason you get that error is because Python is in the process of defining your `inventory` attribute yet you are call `status` which *must* refer to `inventory` to give a return value.

You don't even want to be calling the function and saving the return value in the dictionary since that won't allow you to use it dynamically. You should change it such that you don't invoke but just save the reference.

```
class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = {
            'cash': 500,
            'paycheck': 1,
            'savings': 1000,
            'current_car': 0,
            'possible_cars': ['Chevy', 'Honda', 'BMW'],
            'car_cost': [0, 100, 200],
            'current_house': 0,
            'possible_houses': ['apartment','townhouse','suite'],
            'house_cost': [0, 150, 300],
            'status': self.status  # <--- don't use parens ()
        }
```

And just call the method like,

```
>>> my_inventory = Inventory()
>>> my_inventory.inventory['status']()
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this indeed solved my problem. A follow-up question. I'm using a while loop elsewhere in my code that: while my_inv.inventory['status']() == True ; will this always reference my status() method and update itself if False, or will it save itself as True once and not check itself again?

Comment: @user2570777 That would be fine. It won't save the return value unless you assign it.

Answer (score 1):

I got a different error, but I believe the solution would be the same:

```
class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = {
            'cash': 500,
            'paycheck': 1,
            'savings': 1000,
            'current_car': 0,
            'possible_cars': ['Chevy', 'Honda', 'BMW'],
            'car_cost': [0, 100, 200],
            'current_house': 0,
            'possible_houses': ['apartment','townhouse','suite'],
            'house_cost': [0, 150, 300],
                  }
        self.inventory['status'] = self.status()

    def status(self):
        while self.inventory['cash'] + self.inventory['savings'] > 0:
            return True
```

My error was complaining about inventory not being defined in status().

Answer (score 0):

I tried copying & pasting your code into my Python interpreter and I get a different error:

```
>>> inv = new Inventory()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    inv = new Inventory()
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> inv = Inventory()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in status
AttributeError: 'Inventory' object has no attribute 'inventory'
```

The problem is that you have a cyclic dependency here between `inventory` and `status`. You use `status` to define `inventory`, but `status` needs to read `inventory` before it can return... See the problem?